# I'm getting an error when running npm run deploy

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, github-pages, next.js

I'm trying to deploy my NextJS app to Github pages. I already installed npm gh-pages and was getting errors when I always run `npm run deploy`.

Any thoughts why this is happening?

Here's the error when I run the command:

[image]

While here's my debug log file:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Seems have a problem with `docs/CNAME`. Does it exist?

Comment: @Joseph D. Yes it does

Comment: Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this. I just switch my npm version to 12.15.0 using nvm. I run `nvm use 12.15.0.`